# JavaScript loader function work in Firefox fine but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I have created a JavaScript function which is not working in google chrome and working fine with firefox. Also working with debugging mode in google chrome. Please check my code, what is the problem and solution.

or
I want to force the Chrome debugger for working my code without debuging mode.

HTML

```
<div class="mat-inp mat-select">
    <label for="showTime">Show Time</label>
    <select id="showTime" name="showTime" onchange="timeSelected(this.value,true)" required disabled style="opacity:0.5">
        <option selected value="">Select Show Time</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="mat-inp mat-select">
    <label for="seatClass">Seat Class</label>
    <select id="seatClass" name="seatClass" onclick="checkSeatClassAvailability()" onchange="seatClassSelected(this.value,true)" required disabled style="opacity:0.5">
        <option selected value="">Select Seat Class</option>
    </select>
    <p id="SeatNotAvailable" hidden class="err-msg">No seat available</p>
</div>
```

Javascript Loader Function

```
function ShowProgress() {
      var modal = $('<div/>');
      modal.addClass("load-modal-on-click");
      $('body').append(modal);
      var loading = $(".loader-on-click");
      loading.addClass("show");
      $('body').addClass("add");
}
function hideprogress() {
    var loading = $(".loader-on-click");
    loading.removeClass("show");
    $('body').removeClass("add");
    $('.load-modal-on-click').remove();
}
```

Ajex Loader Function

```
function timeSelected(value, startLoader) {
    if(startLoader){
        ShowProgress();
    }
    showTimeVal = value;
    if(value==null||value==""){
        clearTimeDependents();
    }
    else{
        $("#ShowTimeError").hide();
        var showTimeList = movieScheduleData[theaterVal];
        var selectedTime = $.grep(showTimeList, function (element) {
            return element.slot == showTimeVal;
        })[0];
        selectedShowTime = selectedTime.showTime;
        var request = {dtmid:selectedTime.dtmid, slot:selectedTime.slot};
        var jsonRequest = JSON.stringify(request);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "...........",
            async: false,
            data:jsonRequest,
            dataType:"json",
            contentType:"application/json",
            traditional:true,
            success: function (response) {
                seatStatusData = response;
                if(seatStatusData!=null && seatStatusData.seatInfo!=null){
                    var seatClassList = Object.keys(seatStatusData.seatInfo);
                    var seatClassFullHtml = seatClassBaseHtml;
                    for(var i = 0; i<seatClassList.length; i++){
                        var name = seatClassList[i];
                        var price = seatStatusData.seatInfo[name];
                        var label = name + " " + price + " per ticket"
                        var row = "<option value='"+name+"'>"+label+"</option>";
                        seatClassFullHtml = seatClassFullHtml +''+  row;
                    }
                    document.getElementById("seatClass").innerHTML = seatClassFullHtml;
                    document.getElementById("seatClass").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("seatClass").style.opacity=1;
                    $("#SeatClass").parent().addClass("is-completed");
                    seatClassVal = $("#SeatClass").val();
                    clearClassDependents();
                    hideprogress();
                }
                else{
                    clearTimeDependents();
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                clearTimeDependents();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why async false? It is highly recommended to use Ajax in the manner it was designed

Comment: Also what are the symptoms? Any console errors?

Comment: @ mplungjan, async:true working fine. thank you